# Exporting trac tickets to MS Project

Tags: trac, ms-project

I want to share data between Trac and MS Project. To import data to Trac I can use CSV import plugin, but I don't know if there's a way to export data from Trac to Project. Anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can import data into MS Project from an Excel file.  If you export data from Trac in CSV format, Excel should be able to convert it into an Excel file that can then be imported into Project.  I haven't tried this myself, so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind writing a little code, you could use [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) to create either an MPX or an MSPDI (XML) file which you will be able to import into Microsoft Project.

Jon

p.s. Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ.

Answer (score 0):

you can [contact Task Adapter developers](http://www.taskadapter.com/contacts) to request a Trac connector. it's not worth it if you only need it for a one-off transfer. but it may make sense if you need this kind of tool on a regular basis.